# h1 line-height or height issue when hovering for color change

Tags: html, css, hover, height

I'd like to make color change when hovering `h1` as the code shown below.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
  <style>
    h1 {color:#aef;font-size: 14em;line-height: 0.1;}
    h1:hover {color: #ff9224;}
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>More</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

(The code is also in [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/poyepa/edit?html,output).)

However, I want the color change when hovering on *letters* only, like, in the picture, the letter area below the green line. I had tried `line-height` and `height` to very small values, but both didn't take effect.

Should I change something else? Or just use `p` to replace `h1` for convenience?

[image: hovering green line on the very top of letter]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this snippet i created if it helps

```css
.border {
  overflow: hidden;
}
h1 {
  color: #aef;
  font-size: 14em;
  line-height: 163px;
  margin: 0;
}
h1:hover {
  color: #ff9224;
}
```

```html
<div class="border">
  <h1>More</h1>
</div>
```

Comment: This works! Thanks! But I still don't know how and why, actually.